# add selected Item from Jcombobox to Jlist

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist

i have created a Jcombobox and i have populated it from data base, i have a JList and i want every item i select in the combobox to be added on the JList. i'm new to java and i tried to solve the problem with this code but it's not working :

```
 private void addelementActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

   DefaultListModel liss = new DefaultListModel();

   Object  s = empcombo_s.getSelectedItem().toString();


   for(int i =0; i<=1;i++) { 
    liss.add(i, s);
}

   stagelist.setModel(liss);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). *"..but it's not working :"*  What happens exactly? P.S.  Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Why are you creating a new model every time addelementActionPerformed() is called? This gets rid of the old model and anything that had been added to it.

Why are you adding the selection to the model twice?

Comment: the selected item is added to the list but each time i select a new item, the new on takes the place of the old on and there is no list created

Comment: `for(int i =0; i<=1;i++) {` as an aside.  A 'loop' that only iterates once is not really a loop..

Comment: thank u guys, i just removed the default model from the add methode now everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

now this code is working properly :

```
  DefaultListModel liss = new DefaultListModel();
private void addelementActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

   String  s = empcombo_s.getSelectedItem().toString();
  liss.addElement(s);
   stagelist.setModel(liss);
}
```

Comment: Congrats on working it out, and good job for reporting back.  :)